# How to preview an uploaded image before submitting using FileBase64

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to preview an image after uploading? I implemented the uploading steps but I want to preview the image before tapping on submit.

Code used is here:

```
    const [shop, setShop] = useState({  
      shopName: '', 
      shopPic: '' });

          const onSubmitHandler=(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault()
            axios.post("http://localhost:6001/shops/add", shop)
            .then((res)=>{
                console.log('Saved Successfully')
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
            console.log('Error')
            })
          }

return (
      <div className="allShops">
        <div className="allShopsCont">
          <span className="allShopsPageTitle">
          Add Shop
          </span>

          <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
            <div className="adminShopInputContainer">
            <h9 className="adminShopInputTitles">
              Shop Name
            </h9>
              <input type="text" className="adminShopInput"
                onChange={e => setShop({ ...shop, shopName: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>

            
            <div className="">
              <FileBase64
              type="file"
              multiple={false}
              onDone={({ base64 }) => setShop({ ...shop, shopPic: base64 })}
              />
            </div>

  <div className="">
  <button className="" type="submit">
    <p className="">Submit</p>
    </button>
  </div>
  
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
```

So, I want the preview of uploaded image before Submitting

Answer (score 0):

1. Using FileBase64

```
const [shop, setShop] = useState({
    shopName: "",
    shopPic: ""
  });
  const onImageUpload = async (file) => {
    setShop({ ...shop, shopPic: file });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {shop.shopPic && (
        <div className="image">
          <img src={shop.shopPic} alt={shop.shopPic} />
        </div>
      )}
      <FileBase64
        type="file"
        multiple={false}
        onDone={({ base64 }) => onImageUpload(base64)}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

code sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-roman-5c7te4?file=/src/App.js

2. You can store the uploaded image data to a state using FileReader and use that to show the preview.

```
  const [logo, setLogo] = useState({ fileName: undefined, path: undefined });
  const onImageUpload = async (file) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setLogo({ fileName: file.name, path: reader.result });
    };
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {logo.path && (
        <div className="image">
          <img src={logo.path} alt={logo.path} />
        </div>
      )}
      <button
        className="btn btn-secondary custom-btn"
        type="button"
        onClick={(e) => {
          document.getElementById("image-upload").click();
        }}
      >
        Upload Image
      </button>
      <input
        id="image-upload"
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          onImageUpload(e.currentTarget.files[0]);
        }}
        hidden
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Please refer the sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-snowflake-hq3bol?file=/src/App.js:221-251

Comment: does this work with filebase64? or I don't have to use it?

Comment: @sultan.h I have updated the answer for firebase64 as well.